# I would like to know how to define a Kotlin Job() with 'new' as its state

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, jobs

I don't know how to define a Job as new. I want to define a job to execute it whenever I want, using `start()` method.
The result I get is that the job is executed when I define it.

```
override fun onStart() { 
    super.onStart();
    var idenNuevo:String?=null
    val job1 = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        idenNuevo = insertarUsuario();
    }
    with(thus.bind){
        registroBtnRegistro.setOnClickListener(){
            job1.start()
        }
        runBlocking{
            job1.join()
            runOnUiThread {
                registroTvDebug.text = "$idenNuevo"
            }

        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set a different `start` parameter, [the default puts the `Job` in the *active* state](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html):

```
val job1 = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default, start=CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
```

> By default, the coroutine is immediately scheduled for execution. Other start options can be specified via `start` parameter. See `CoroutineStart` for details. An optional start parameter can be set to `CoroutineStart.LAZY` to start coroutine *lazily*. In this case, the coroutine Job is created in *new* state. It can be explicitly started with `start` function and will be started implicitly on the first invocation of `join`.

Comment: Hi, first thank you so much for your answer. I was already trying to set the parameter 'start' as you show in your post, but with the code I shared above I was still getting the execution. Now due to your answer, I' ve realized what was my mistake. In my code I use join() but I didn't know it triggers the execution, I thought it just waits for the job to finish.